# PyGears - Infinite while loop in import statement

Tags: python, windows, pygears

When importing pygears:

```
from pygears import gear, Intf
```

The execution reaches `__init__.py`. In the `__init__.py` script, on line 54 the following function is called:

```
load_rc('.pygears')
```

This function is defined in custom_settings.py. The execution of my program seems to be stuck in the following while loop:

```
while dirname != '/':
  search_dirs.append(dirname)
  dirname = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirname, '..'))
```

This loop seems to be trying to get to the abs path of my drive. The original value of the variable dirname is the location of my project on my C drive. The loop gets stuck because its travels through the folder stack all the way to `C:\\`. Since " C:\\ " is not equal to "/", the loop continues indefinitely.

Is a specific project structure needed to avoid this problem, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for reporting and providing such a detailed analysis. We've fixed the issue on master.

Problem is that PyGears is predominantly tested on Linux. And even though the framework is not OS dependent these issues might occur on non-Linux systems.

Also, please report such issues on PyGears Github so that we can attend to it better.

Thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27371810)

Comment: @peeebeee Actually, author can solve the question by fixing the code in master.